# RSA Group theory proof

Tags: group-theory, cryptography

Let $q,p$ prime numbers and $n=pq$.
Let $r$ random from $Z^{*}_n$ and $e$ random element which is not contained in $\varphi(n)$.
all values except $p$ and $q$ are known.

Let

$f_1(m) = m^e \text{ mod } n$

$f_0(m) = rm^e \text{ mod } n$

Assuming RSA problem is hard in $Z^{*}_n$ show that it is not possible to find $x,y$ such as $f_1(x)=f_0(y)$.

I know that I need to use reduction to the RSA problem, but I'm not quite sure how?

Comment: $f_1(0)=f_2(0)$ -- so I assume we only allow $w\in\Bbb Z_n^\times$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$f_1(x)=f_0(y) \iff x^e\equiv ry^e\pmod n\iff (xy^{-1})^e\equiv r\pmod n.$$
As inverting is easy in $\Bbb Z_n^\times$, finding such $x,y$ allows us to decrypt $r$, which is assumed hard for random $r$.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that gcd(y, n) might be >1? Then, y might not have an inverse at all in modulo n field.